# Knockout bind select to radio button

Tags: knockout.js, radio-button

Let say I have :

```
function viewModel(){
    this.mySelect=ko.observable();
    this.myRadio=ko.observable();
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

<select data-bind="value: mySelect">
    <option>select you language</option>
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="Italian">Italian</option>
</select>

Need translator:
<input type="radio" name="needTransaltor" value="Y" data-bind="checked: myRadio">Yes
<input type="radio" name="needTransaltor" value="N" data-bind="checked: myRadio">No
```

How can I:
Checked radio button "No" and assign value "No" to `this.myRadio` if user choose "English" from drop down?

Comment: I write function in Jquery which checked radio button, but it did not change observable value.

Comment: It sounds like you may have a misunderstanding about the purpose or usage of knockout. I suggest you start with the documentation and examples. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a possible solution below.  use the checked binding for the radio button and the options binding for the select.  then for the value binding on the select I used a writable computed observable http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html  to change the radio button if the user chose English.  you can run the example below. choose a language besides english, set the need translator to Yes then change the language to english and the radio button will update to No.

```js
function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.availableLanguages = ko.observableArray([
    'English',
    'French',
    'Italian'
  ]);
  this.needTranslator = ko.observable('N');
  this.language = ko.observable('');

  this.selectedLanguage = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function() {
      return this.language();
    },
    write: function(value) {
      if (value === 'English') {
        this.needTranslator('N');
      }
      this.language(value);
    },
    owner: this
  });


}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  choose language:
  <select data-bind="options: availableLanguages,
value: selectedLanguage,          optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
</p>

Need Translator:
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="needTranslator" value="N" data-bind="checked: needTranslator" />No</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="needTranslator" value="Y" data-bind="checked: needTranslator" />Yes</div>
```